# Google Ads API Java Client Library: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull

Tags: scala, sbt, google-ads-api

Trying to use [Google Ads API Java Client Library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib) to access Adwords API (code snippet taken from project README):

```
val credential = new OfflineCredentials.Builder()
  .forApi(OfflineCredentials.Api.ADWORDS)
  .withClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
  .withRefreshToken(refreshToken)
  .build()
  .generateCredential()
```

This fails with error:

```
[info] Exception encountered when attempting to run a suite with class name: AdwordsClientSpec *** ABORTED ***
[info]   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
[info]   at com.google.api.ads.common.lib.auth.OfflineCredentials$Api.<init>(OfflineCredentials.java:89)
[info]   at com.google.api.ads.common.lib.auth.OfflineCredentials$Api.<clinit>(OfflineCredentials.java:81)
[info]   at AdwordsClient$.generateAdwordsCredential(AdwordsClient.scala:24)
[info]   at AdwordsClientSpec$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AdwordsClientSpec.scala:23)
[info]   at AdwordsClientSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(AdwordsClientSpec.scala:18)
[info]   at AdwordsClientSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(AdwordsClientSpec.scala:18)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
```

Seems like some dependencies are not resolved correctly. I use the most recent versions of both artefacts mentioned in the README with sbt:

```
 "com.google.api-ads" % "ads-lib" % "3.5.0",
 "com.google.api-ads" % "adwords-axis" % "3.5.0"
```

Comment: This looks like a Guava version conflict - do you have any Guava dependencies (direct or transitive) in your project? (besides the one used within Google API library). If you're unsure - please edit the post to include _all_ of your SBT dependencies.

Comment: @TzachZohar thanks for this tip, it was a useful point of departure for solving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TzachZoha pointed out, a version conflict with Guava is present. `com.google.api-ads` uses Guava 16.0 rather than Guava 20.0. I was able to make my code compile by changing sbt build definition:

```
  ("com.google.api-ads" % "ads-lib" % "3.5.0").exclude(
    "com.google.guava", "guava"),
  "com.google.api-ads" % "adwords-axis" % "3.5.0",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "20.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by removing the Google Collections jar from my lib folder, which had come along with some other jars; see https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-collections/#